# Create a basic network app

Tags: java, android, web-services

I have a little question about an android app with a function "remote" use via internet.

So I have these ideas:

- Create a webservice using php on the server, and refresh the client app all x time like 4-5 sec
- Or make a java server (so I don't know how I can do that)

I just want make a remote connected via user/password to the server and the other app connect to the server and refresh his status.

Do you know the best way for do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not very precise, but as far as I understand it, both your ideas implement the 'pull' concept, that is the client app checking the status of the server every now and then.

If you want the app to be instantly notified of the server status change, I would suggest push notifications with GCM (Google Clound Messaging). You can find some basic descriptions and examples at: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Sending a server-to-client notification is simple regardless of the platform you use server side. E.g. for PHP integration with GCM, check out this thread: [GCM with PHP (Google Cloud Messaging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging)

Comment: Sorry if this is not precise.

So i have one app "the client" in this app i want modify some variable with an other app "The remote"

For that i need a server for check user, pass and connect the remote to the client and after change variable with the remote.

i don'nt need push notification but i need "live interaction" between the client and the remote.

with PHP solution this is not "live" like 4-5 sec delay....

Comment: OK, I get it now. It looks like you need to establish a two-way connectivity using sockets. This thread may give you some idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653481/java-two-way-socket-connection-server-client
You may also think of utilizing some existing protocol, like WebSockets (http://autobahn.ws/) or implement your own with Netty (http://netty.io/) if it gets more complicated.